# How to check for opening and closing tags in xml file using java?

Tags: java

I have a xml file like the following:

```
<file>
     <students>
          <student>
               <name>Arthur</name>
               <height>168</height>
          </student>
          <student>
               <name>John</name>
               <height>176</height>
          </student>
     </students>
</file>
```

How do I check whether for each opening tag, there is an ending tag? For example, if I do not provide the ending tag as:

```
<file>
     <students>
          <student>
               <name>Arthur</name>
               <height>168</height>
          // Ending tag for student missing here
          <student>
               <name>John</name>
               <height>176</height>
          </student>
     </students>
</file>
```

How do I continue parsing the rest of the file?

I tried with SAX parser as explained [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/), but its not very suitable for me as it throws an exception in case I do not provide a closing tag as in the second xml code I provided.

Comment: And what would you want it to do instead of throwing an exception?

Comment: why is it not suitable? you can try/catch the exception and move onwards.

Comment: Instead of that you should correct the xml file.Or if someone else is making that,then inform them.

Comment: You actually don't know if the ending tag is missing for the first or the second `<student>`. One of those is not closed.

Comment: Why do you want to parse an XML file which is not well formed? If the producer of the XML file can't ensure a well formed XML, then the consumer should not take it on itself to process the corrupt XML file.

Comment: To be generous to the user who might make multiple errors, I would rather like to read what he/ she inputs, and suggest him/her the possible errors that he has made.

Comment: Are you implementing some kind of XML editor? If so, I understand your requirement. If not, just tell th user that the XML is invalid, and tell your users to use an XML editor that will show them the errors. Also, note that SAXParseException has a line and a column number, so you can at least point the user to the location of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An XML file that does not verify your condition "for each opening tag, there is an ending tag", is not *[well formed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formedness_and_error-handling)*. 
To check that an XML file is well formed is the first job of a XML parser (it's its first task). Hence, you need a XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you found has a bug in it. `characters()` maybe called multiple times for the same element ([source](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#characters%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)). The proper way to mark the end of an element is to reset the respective boolean states inside of `endElement()`. The [comments section](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/#comment-77769) has code that shows the required change.

With that issue fixed, you can do error checking in `startElement()` to ensure that the file is not trying to start an invalid element given the current state. This will also allow you to ensure that a `name` element is only found inside of a `student` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the following algorithm (pseudo-code):

```
String xml = ...
stack = new Stack()

while True:

    tag = extractNextTag(xml)

    // no new tag is found
    if tag == null:
       break

    if (tag.isOpening()):
        stack.push(tag.name)
    else:
        oldTagName = stack.pop()
        if (oldTagName != tag.name):
            error("Open/close tag error")
if ! stack.isEmpty():
    error("Open/close tag error")
```

you can implement function extractNewTag with 10-20 lines of codes using some knowled about parsers or just writing simple regular expression.
Of course when you search for a new tag you need to start searching from the symbol that follows the last tag you found.